# Build error while running the native script application

Tags: android-emulator, migration, build.gradle, nativescript, build-error

Migrating my native script application to 8.1.5 version.
Fixed the errors that occurs when migrating the native script application.
Application build successfully in the emulator. After build successfully getting error in the application.

[image: Click here to see error image]

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Go to AVD Manager, and click `wipe data` on the selected emulator:
[image]

Restart your machine (adb connection might be lost).

Then restart your project by running:

```
ns clear
ns run android
```

If that doesn't open the app on the emulator, run:

```
ns devices
```

Spot the emulator ID you want to run the app on

```
ns build android
ns deploy --device EMULATOR-ID
```

Note:
Make sure you've done all 4 blue steps in the cli message (in blue).

Comment: I'm running in my real device, Still facing the same issue . How to fix it?